# Is continuity the same as domain being all real numbers?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Basically, my question is—

**Is this statement:**

f(x) is continuous for all x.

**the same as?**

The domain of f(x) is all real numbers.

Comment: they are very different concepts.

Comment: "$f(x)$ is *defined* for all $x$" is the same as "the domain of $f$ is all real numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the function defined as $f(x)=1, x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then its domain is all real numbers, but it is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same. There are functions which are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ but are not continuous. Consider $f$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x\ge 0$. However implicit in the statement that $f$ is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is that $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if } x\neq 0\\ 0 \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

No, they are different concepts:

- [Continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)
- [Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive answer.  Not at all.  Domain being all real numbers means you need an answer for $f(x)$ for any $x$, but it could jump around a lot.  Continuity means $f(x)$ is close to $f(x')$ if $x$ is close to $x'$.  They are wildly different.